# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Single Abs(Single)' method

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

We would expect that LINQ to Entities would be able to handle a absolute value function.  It seem that is cannot translate the linq to sql.  We are using .net 3.5.  Is there another way to express this query to work with Linq to Entities?  The absolute value we are using is part of the entity/DB table.  See the code sample below.

```
ListItemIds = sessionDB.ListItems
.Where(x => x.ListItemId >= x.List.StartId && x.ListItemId <= x.List.EndId)
.Where(x => (x.Dr != null)||(Math.Abs(x.Dr.Value) >= rangeDB))
.Select(x => x.ListItemId).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you have a small logic error not related to your `Math.Abs`, The seccond where clause should be "*.Where(x => (x.Dr != null) **&&** (Math.Abs(x.Dr.Value) >= rangeDB))*" By using `||` you could get a null reference on `x.Dr.Value` (assuming `Math.Abs` worked, p.s.w.g answer is likely the solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mathematical terms, `|x| >= y` is true if either `x >= y` or `-x >= y` (which is equivalent to `x <= -y`), so you could just check the positive and negative values of `Dr.Value`.

However, [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041008/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-single-abssingle-method/19041022?noredirect=1#comment28140215_19041022) is right; the way you check for null is wrong as well. Use this if you only want records where the `Dr` property *is not* null **and** `Dr.Value` is within the provided range (i.e. null's are excluded):

```
ListItemIds = sessionDB.ListItems
  .Where(x => x.ListItemId >= x.List.StartId && x.ListItemId <= x.List.EndId)
  .Where(x => (x.Dr != null)&&((x.Dr.Value >= rangeDB)||(x.Dr.Value <= -rangeDB)))
  .Select(x => x.ListItemId).ToList();
```

Or this for records where `Dr` *is* null **or** `Dr.Value` is within the provided range (i.e. null's are included):

```
ListItemIds = sessionDB.ListItems
  .Where(x => x.ListItemId >= x.List.StartId && x.ListItemId <= x.List.EndId)
  .Where(x => (x.Dr == null)||(x.Dr.Value >= rangeDB)||(x.Dr.Value <= -rangeDB))
  .Select(x => x.ListItemId).ToList();
```

Comment: I think the OP made a error on the null check, it should be a `&&` not a `||`, I only say because it changes slightly the 2nd part (it would require a extra set of parenthesis).